# How To Create Native Tab Bar floating above

Tags: phonegap-build, tabbar, cordova-3, intel-xdk

I am a beginner. I want to create android app using intel XDK. how to implement facebook or twitter button on the menu in order to open up their web while tab bar to return to the main menu it floating above like this: [fixed tab bar sample](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yOVUqHOGpuo/VEH02XZ8IYI/AAAAAAAAAAM/6vcIdAmTdfY/s1600/sample-fixed-tab-bar.jpg)

Anyone please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list view` or `grid view` template available in Intel XDK, and add iframe in the `panels`, the `header` will stay in place

Comment: I have done it but when i load an external page, loading components are not perfect and some pages even not working properly.

Comment: are u testing in emulator? try in app-preview or build and install app and test

Comment: I have done it in my device but I can not download/save file from website to my device storage.